# Why 10^1 is 11?

Tags: c++, math, caret

I am currently learning *C++*. I was trying to compute power of an integer using the expression:

```
val=10^1;
```

Instead of expected answer `10`, the result was `11`. I have fixed the problem by using `pow` function of math.h library but I am wondering why this statement is giving me the wrong result.

Comment: hint: you can delete your own posts ...

Comment: @Walter: Other people can make the same mistake. It will allow them to find it and not ask the same question.

Comment: @Walter: Not when they have upvoted answers.

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes, it is a pretty reasonable mistake to make for a learner

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Just some unlucky day and a very silly question in the world of top programmers.

Comment: Yet a question likely to pop up quite often, so it's nice to have this on SO. And I also falls in this trap, when switching languages: for power, c has `pow`, fortran has `**`, gap and maxima have `^`, now guess what is `2^3` in python ? I *know* it's xor and python has `**` for power. But sometimes a devil makes me type too fast.

Comment: Just two more votes for a nice question badge and 500 reputation perks.

Comment: So here's a downvote, mkay :-P

Comment: @Heliac Keep incoming

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Actually all the answers are good and is difficult to determine which one is best. So, I haven't accepted any answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the *bitwise exclusive-or* operator, not power. In binary:

```
10 = 1010
 1 = 0001
val= 1011 = 11 in decimal
```

Answer (score 10):

No! Do you think that is the power? Don't forgot this (In C++ and some of the programming languages):
[image]

Be sure to read this:

- Operators ([cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators))
- Bitwise operation ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation))

---

A bitwise **XOR** takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the logical exclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The result in each position is 1 if only the first bit is 1 or only the second bit is 1, but will be 0 if both are 0 or both are 1. In this we perform the comparison of two bits, being 1 if the two bits are different, and 0 if they are the same. For example:

```
    0101 (decimal 5)
XOR 0011 (decimal 3)
  = 0110 (decimal 6)
```

The bitwise XOR may be used to invert selected bits in a register (also called toggle or flip). Any bit may be toggled by XORing it with 1. For example, given the bit pattern 0010 (decimal 2) the second and fourth bits may be toggled by a bitwise XOR with a bit pattern containing 1 in the second and fourth positions:

```
    0010 (decimal 2)
XOR 1010 (decimal 10)
  = 1000 (decimal 8)
```

This technique may be used to manipulate bit patterns representing sets of Boolean states.

**Source: Wikipedia**

Comment: In Haskell, `x^n` does raise `x` to an integral power.

Comment: @ larsmans - Amended: in many programming languages, thank you so much.

Comment: ([Visual] Basic [.NET], too!)

Comment: @minitech:      Amended Again: In some of the programming languages, thank you so much.

Comment: Add Lua to the languages that use `^` for power not exclusive-or. Lua's `^` operator allows both operands to be non-integral to boot.

Answer (score 5):

In C and C++, `10^1` is `10 XOR 1`, not `10 to the power of 1`.

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the binary `XOR` operator in C++:

```
10 ^ 1 = 

   00001010
^  00000001
=  --------
   00001011 = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ^ is the exclusive or operator and not the exponentiation operator. Basically, because the last bit of 10 in binary is 0, by applying exclusive or of 1 the last bit gets converted to 1 because it is different than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because in C++ there is no power operator: `^` is a `XOR`.

`10`<sub>10</sub> is `1010`<sub>2</sub> in binary; `1`<sub>10</sub> is `0001`<sub>2</sub>. `XOR`ing them together gives `1011`<sub>2</sub>, which is `11`<sub>10</sub>.

If you would like to obtain 10<sup>n</sup>, use the [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) function from `<cmath>` header:

```
val=pow(10, 1);
```

Comment: downvoted because of promoting pow for calculating integer powers of integers.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala There is nothing wrong with using pow for calculating powers of integers, because all considerations against it usually fall into the "premature optimization" category.