# C - forcing the type of an arithmetic expression

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long long int x = 4294967296;
  long long int y = 2^32; // 4294967296
  printf("%lld \n", x);
  printf("%lld \n", y);
}
```

It outputs:

```
4294967296
34
```

This is a contrived example but how can I force an arithmetic expression to a wider type? I tried something like

```
(2LL)^(32LL)
```

but does not work.
I'm compiling with gcc on 64-bit Ubuntu.

.

// EDIT

Obviously I'm a noob and did not realize ^ is not the exponential operator but bitwise XOR... I'll now shamefully go back to learning C

Comment: ^ is an exclusive or.  Did you mean << or pow()?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730348/why-101-is-11

Comment: There is no "x to the power of y" operator in C.

Comment: You want to use #include <math.h> and you probably want to use pow() or powl(). You are indeed XORing with ^

Comment: Or at least `long long int y = 1; int n = 32; while (n--) y *= 2;`

Comment: not sure this is duplicate, one can consider this as an overflow issue rather the XOR instead of `pow()` - in that case the answers are relavnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others noted `^` is *exclusive or*, in most languages.

The best way to compute an integer power of 2 is to use bit shifting, not floating point `pow` as you could lose precision (for powers of other numbers there are good algorithms too: [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)).

But for that you have to make sure the result doesn't overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   long long int y = 1LL<<32;

   printf("%lld\n",y);

}
```

The other trap here is that you cannot shift `1` 32 times without using the `LL` prefix, otherwise overflow occurs *before* assigning to `long long` (see [Overflow appears even when using unsigned long int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281718/overflow-appears-even-when-using-unsigned-long-int)) unless the `int` type is 64 bit. I wouldn't bet on it, and most compilers warn you about the overflow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

first, the result you got is correct because you are actually XORing the value

second, at least in your case you can shift the output by 32 but in that case you need to make sure that the value you are about to shift is at least 64bit long in order to prevent overflow hence you nust use something like:

```
unsigned long long test = 1LLU << 32;
```

note the `LLU` where the '2' primitive is set to at-least 64bit width before the shift.
casting in this case won't work since the calculated output already overflowed

Comment: note that `2<<32 ==
8589934592`, which is `pow(2,33)`

Comment: Thanks, edited...

Comment: errr, now you've doubled it again

Comment: fixing comments on your phone is a bad idea... my mistake